# How to rerender a child component based on a change in JS array

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a LWC that includes a child component, which displays a Lightning Datatable.
On initial load, based on `@api` decorator property: `tableData`, the table renders with valid data.

But, when we try to filter the data based on a criteria, i.e., updating this `tableData` property, the child component that holds the datatable is not getting re-rendered.  Meaning, the data is not getting refreshed.

I have referred many SFSE questions: [One](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354823/lwc-lightning-datatable-not-refreshing-when-data-changes), [two](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/368392/44898), and many others. But still, the child component is not getting triggered or reloading with new data for the `tableData` property. Here is my attempt:

```
this.tableData = [...tabDataList];
let tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableData ));
let removedEle = tempData.shift();
tempData.push(removedEle);
this.tableData = tempData;
```

From the browser console, I can see the `tableData` getting changed, but that is not working as a `reactive` property to reload the child component that renders the actual datatable.

Is there any way we can reload the child component once we update the tableData property? Like, making it reactive, or, rerendering the entire child component.

Comment: can you post html files for child and parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list defined in your parent component, you'll need to mutate it there. The child component should refresh automatically then. Bear in mind that using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does not work. But if you reassign the value to the data variable, then the refresh process will be triggered accordingly. Example below uses [`.toSpliced`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced).

```js
// parent component
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  data = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Martha"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Lauren"},
  ];

  handleRemoveItem() {
    // this mutates the array in-place, so it DOES NOT WORK 
    this.data.splice(this.data.length - 1, 1)

    // this one, however, changes the data and reassigns the value to the 
    // data variable, triggering the refresh to the child component as well
    this.data = this.data.toSpliced(this.data.length - 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- child component's implementation on parent -->
<c-child data={data}></c-child>
```

```js
// child component
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

const COLS = [
  {label: "Name", fieldName: "name"}
]

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
  @api data = [];
  columns = COLS;
}
```

Comment: Hi @RenatoOliveira, I think the above approach might work just fine, but I ended up using a different approach. I have used a Boolean variable for reactive purposes of the child component and used a dummy datatable to make it visible/hide while the system processing the filter logic. Once the filter execution is done, I am refreshing the Boolean variable which reloads the entire child component with latest filtered data.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `@track` property for the tableData variable to track changes in the object property. Normal variables are by default reactive, but `@track` is needed for objects.

Comment: The @track Decorator Is No Longer Required for Lightning Web Components. All fields in a Lightning web component class are reactive. If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value. [Source](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&release=224&type=5). Meaning, `@track` wont fix the issue I am facing.

Comment: @track is needed for objects. For normal variables by default reactive so not needed.